# How can I change the templating framework in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, template-engine, mustache

I want to integrate Mustache into my Django app. What steps would I need to take to completely replace Django's templating system with Mustache?

I would like to have render_to_response work properly with Mustache templates, passing in all the right variables with the context (STATIC_URL, request, etc.).

Answer (score 6):

Basically, you have to replace the `render_to_response` function with your own implementation that uses the template system of your choice. Django's `render_to_response` is specific to Django's templating system. This function simply wraps some common grunt-work used when using the django template engine. The basics on how they work are covered in [Django's tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/#write-views-that-actually-do-something).

Use the `django.template.RequestContext` to acquire all the context variables specified in the `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting, (where STATIC_URL, request, etc. get defined). Since `RequestContext` behaves like a dictionary, you should be able to pass it through to mustache without problems. `RequestContext` takes the request object in its constructor.

Finally, don't forget to return the proper [HttpResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-objects) object!

Since I'm not much of a paragraph fan:

1. Create RequestContext instance.
2. Merge dictionary received with RequestContext instance.
3. Render the template to a string.
4. Wrap the final string with a HttpResponse instance.